# Can one use [CustomAttribute] with anonymous in-line delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates, custom-attributes

With the [attribute] notation I can attach custom attributes to class instance methods.  But if I write code like

```
menu.handlers[MOUSECLICK] += (clickEvent)delegate(event e) { ... };
```

the [attribute] notation seems not to be available.  Am I limited to attributes for methods declared out of line, or is there a way to somehow do them for in-line anonymous methods declared using delegate() { ... }?

(I happen to like the inline style: you have easy access to in-scope variables and I think it makes for a nicer and more compact kind of code where you can see what the event handler will do at the same place where you register it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The anonymous method is defined in-line and not as a member method of
>   any class. Additionally, there is no way to apply custom attributes to
>   an anonymous method, nor can the anonymous method define generic types
>   or add generic constraints.

Quoting from the MSDN Article - [Create Elegant Code With Anonymous Methods, Iterators, And Partial Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163682.aspx)

In Short NO!, You cannot add custom attributes for Anonymous methods