# Usage of AttributeTargets.Delegate

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926378/can-one-use-customattribute-with-anonymous-in-line-delegates) stackoverflow answer you can't apply a custom attribute to an anonymous method.

What is [`AttributeTargets.Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then for?

Is it for another .NET language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anonymous methods are not delegates. [Delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) are declarations of method types.

For example:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Delegate)]
public class DelegateTargetAttribute : Attribute
{ }

public class Example
{
    [DelegateTarget]
    public delegate int Foo (string bar);
}
```